# Inline JavaScript throwing "not defined" (it IS!) - WordPress related maybe?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

```
<style>
#flamingo-picture-2 {
 border-width: 15px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: red;
}
</style>
<script>
function changeBorderColor(){
 var img = document.getElementById('flamingo-picture-2');
 if ( img.style.border-color == 'red' ) {
  img.style.border-color = 'blue';
 } else {
  img.style.border-color = 'red';
 }
}
</script>

<img id="flamingo-picture-2" src="/wp-content/uploads/flamingo.jpg" onclick="changeBorderColor()">
```

This is inside a WordPress post content. (I know -- bad practice. But it is just a little demo/example.)

Console shows an error that `changeBorderColor` is not defined. I keep staring at it. I feel like I defined it. Did I miss a brace or a semi-colon or something? Is it possible WordPress is doing something? (I don't *think* it is, as I've looked at the output page source, but you never know...)

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of your developer tools showing the `<script>` and `<img>`? I was under the assumption scripting was stripped from post bodies, or (if not stripped entirely) converted to text/html-special-chars.

Comment: Check the console again. The first error is `Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`. In other words, `img.style.border-color` should be `img.style.borderColor`. Working example -> https://jsfiddle.net/dhg7j731/

Comment: @JoshCrozier -- That works! If you make it an answer, I'll accept it and you win the points. Thank you.

Comment: @AdamWood Thanks, but someone just posted it. As a side note, it's worth mentioning that you could alternatively use bracket notation: `img.style['border-color']`... https://jsfiddle.net/udwxo79s/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `img.style.border-color` you need `img.style.borderColor` It works here:

```js
function changeBorderColor(){
 var img = document.getElementById('flamingo-picture-2');
 if ( img.style.borderColor == 'red' ) {
  img.style.borderColor = 'blue';
 } else {
  img.style.borderColor = 'red';
 }
}
```

```css
#flamingo-picture-2 {
 border-width: 15px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<img id="flamingo-picture-2" src="/wp-content/uploads/flamingo.jpg" onclick="changeBorderColor()">
```